# How to configure formatting rules in Google Dart Editor

Tags: formatting, dart, text-editor, usability, dart-editor

I want configure the Dart Editor for the formatting a such source code without a breaking the first line on parameter list.

Result of formatting.

```dart
String _expand(
    List fragments, Map<String, MacroDefinition> definitions, String defaultValue, Set<String> processed) {
  //
}
```

Is this possible in Dart Editor?

```dart
String _expand(List fragments, Map<String, MacroDefinition> definitions, String defaultValue,
    Set<String> processed) {
  //
}
```

P.S.

The above source code formatted with a 120 characters per line.

Answer (score 3):

You can't configure anything but the line length in DartFormat. It was a deliberate decision to not support formats which deviate from the default format.

Comment: Can you explain what means a `default format`? And what is a reason in such ascetic options (has no choice)?

Comment: Dart style guide https://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/. If the output doesn't conform to the style guide report a bug.

Comment: You really think that you well know the style-guide when you answer? I cannot find in style guide rules about that how to place (format) a function parameters when they don't fits in a single line. Can you give here link to the concrete rule in the style guide? You you don't know this rule?

Comment: The lack of uniformity (in this case) generates chaos. Chaotic formatting styles are not the best solution. However, I am not surprised by anything (in Dart). Thank you for your answer that does not helps.

Comment: Why would I care if there exists a rule. The question was if dartformat can be configured. If you think this doesn't conform to the style guide create a bug report. I don't see what's there to discuss about.

Comment: You say: "Why would I care if there exists a rule". I agree with you. But why was need give here a link to the style-guide? There is no rules for such case in style-guide. Or you want answer: "Why should I care about that what I wrote here?". Nevertheless, you have written that there exists a relation, but about details you don't know anything. Why then you mention here about that which have no relation to the subject?

Comment: The rule actually is pretty simple: Lines will be broken to the next line automatically if they are above the limit. The same applies for parameter. If there parameter is over the "line" it will be written in the next line and indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: @Robert `The rule actually is pretty simple`: The simpler the better. The same problem with Dart Editor. Editor are so pretty simple that it just sometimes shocking.